# Custom pixel information in MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have generated an array of processed data for each pixel in my image. I want to use the `impixelinfo` function to show the pixel information. However, it only shows the RGB value with respective x and y coordinates. How can I append the processed data into the info box?

**Example of the RGB info box**

[image: Example of the RGB info box]

Comment: I don't get what you're asking.  What is "the processed data"?

Comment: like i have convert RGB to another colour space. How i show the value of the respective colour space value

Comment: Use an actual data cursor.  Don't use `impixelinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
imshow(uint8(image));
dcm_obj = datacursormode(gca);
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',{@myupdatefcn,image,other parameter});
function txt = myupdatefcn(empt,event_obj,image,other parameter)
pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
img = image(pos(2),pos(1),:);

txt = {['X:',num2str(pos(1)),' Y:',num2str(pos(2))],...
    ['R:',num2str(img(1,1,1)),' G:',num2str(img(1,1,2)),' B:',num2str(img(1,1,3))]
       };
end
```

Comment: Was this intended as an addition to your Question ?.. But this looks about right. Now you only need to change the txt to what ever you want to display there.

Comment: Sorry, it is the answer, i write wrong word. Thanks for your advice!